# Is there some example xml for the FormInfo list for the updateCredentialsForItem1?

Tags: yodlee

I have been receiving the following error when trying to post updated login credentials:

`<Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Can not invoke the getTypeObject method in the extension mapper class...`

I am accessing the SOAP API via a rails app using the savon gem.

addItemForContentService is working with the same xsi:type definition, and I have used getLoginFormCredentialsForItem to retrieve FormInfos to push back into updateCredentialsForItem1, with no success.

If I could just get some sample xml (that works) for this call I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the parameters you are sending are incorrect or the WSDL format.

For your reference below is XML for **updateCredentialsForItem1**(you need to change values):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <updateCredentialsForItem1 xmlns="http://itemmanagement.accountmanagement.core.soap.yodlee.com">
      <userContext xmlns="">
        <cobrandId>134131232</cobrandId>
        <channelId>-1</channelId>
        <locale>
          <country>US</country>
          <language>en</language>
          <variant></variant>
        </locale>
        <tncVersion>2</tncVersion>
        <applicationId>7A367HGJ621219F00</applicationId>
        <cobrandConversationCredentials xsi:type="ns1:SessionCredentials" xmlns:ns1="http://login.ext.soap.yodlee.com">
          <sessionToken>YOUR_COBRAND_CONVERSATION_TOKEN_VALUE</sessionToken>
        </cobrandConversationCredentials>
        <preferenceInfo>
          <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
          <timeZone>PST</timeZone>
          <dateFormat>MM/dd/yyyy</dateFormat>
          <currencyNotationType>SYMBOL_NOTATION</currencyNotationType>
          <numberFormat>
            <decimalSeparator>.</decimalSeparator>
            <groupingSeparator>,</groupingSeparator>
            <groupPattern>###,##0.##</groupPattern>
          </numberFormat>
        </preferenceInfo>
        <fetchAllLocaleData>false</fetchAllLocaleData>
        <conversationCredentials xsi:type="ns2:SessionCredentials" xmlns:ns2="http://login.ext.soap.yodlee.com">
          <sessionToken>USER_CONVERSATION_TOKEN_VALUE</sessionToken>
        </conversationCredentials>
        <valid>true</valid>
        <isPasswordExpired>false</isPasswordExpired>
      </userContext>
      <itemId xmlns="">1219123123</itemId>
      <credentialFields xmlns="">
        <elements xsi:type="ns3:SecureFieldInfoSingle" xmlns:ns3="http://common.soap.yodlee.com">
          <name>LOGIN</name>
          <displayName>Username</displayName>
          <isEditable>true</isEditable>
          <isOptional>false</isOptional>
          <isEscaped>false</isEscaped>
          <helpText>2212059</helpText>
          <isOptionalMFA>false</isOptionalMFA>
          <isMFA>false</isMFA>
          <value>ACTUAL_USERNAME</value>
          <valueIdentifier>LOGIN</valueIdentifier>
          <valueMask>LOGIN_FIELD</valueMask>
          <fieldType>TEXT</fieldType>
          <size>20</size>
          <maxlength>40</maxlength>
        </elements>
        <elements xsi:type="ns4:SecureFieldInfoSingle" xmlns:ns4="http://common.soap.yodlee.com">
          <name>PASSWORD1</name>
          <displayName>Password</displayName>
          <isEditable>true</isEditable>
          <isOptional>false</isOptional>
          <isEscaped>false</isEscaped>
          <helpText>22121258</helpText>
          <isOptionalMFA>false</isOptionalMFA>
          <isMFA>false</isMFA>
          <value>ACTUAL_PASSWORD_VALUE</value>
          <valueIdentifier>PASSWORD1</valueIdentifier>
          <valueMask>LOGIN_FIELD</valueMask>
          <fieldType>PASSWORD</fieldType>
          <size>20</size>
          <maxlength>40</maxlength>
        </elements>
        <elements xsi:type="ns5:FieldInfoSingle" xmlns:ns5="http://common.soap.yodlee.com">
          <name></name>
          <displayName>Verify Password</displayName>
          <isEditable>true</isEditable>
          <isOptional>false</isOptional>
          <isEscaped>false</isEscaped>
          <helpText>22121258</helpText>
          <isOptionalMFA>false</isOptionalMFA>
          <isMFA>false</isMFA>
          <value>ACTUAL_PASSWORD_VALUE</value>
          <valueIdentifier>PASSWORD1</valueIdentifier>
          <valueMask>LOGIN_FIELD</valueMask>
          <fieldType>PASSWORD</fieldType>
          <size>20</size>
          <maxlength>40</maxlength>
        </elements>
      </credentialFields>
      <startRefreshItemOnUpdate xmlns="">false</startRefreshItemOnUpdate>
    </updateCredentialsForItem1>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```